# В порядке ли всё с пунктуацией?

Tags: пунктуация

Сердце требует перемен, но мозг их боится. Поэтому, отключаем мозги и действуем!

Answer (score 2):

После "поэтому" запятая не нужна – нет причин для постановки.

Интересны ваши резоны – здесь ведь даже и паузы нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Сердце требует перемен, но мозг их боится. Поэтому отключаем мозги и действуем!**

По правилам после местоимения ***поэтому*** нельзя поставить запятую, так как оно используется в качестве **структурного элемента** со значением следствия (выступает как **аналог присоединительного союза** в начале предложения).

Но смысловую авторскую **паузу**  можно обозначить, если заменить местоимение синонимами (вводными словами или другими сочетаниями, выражающими следствие):

(1) Сердце требует перемен, но мозг их боится. Следовательно (значит), отключаем мозги и действуем!

(2)Сердце требует перемен, но мозг их боится. Из этого следует: отключаем мозги и действуем!

Answer (score 1):

Правилами никаких знаков препинания после "поэтому" в приведённом выше предложении не требуется. И прочитано оно будет без этих знаков на едином дыхании, без пауз.

Но…  может, автору хочется **передать** акцент на слове "поэтому" и паузу перед следующим за ним выводом (такое прочтение этого предложения вполне возможно)?

Тогда стоит рассмотреть такой вариант:

*Сердце требует перемен, но мозг их боится. **Поэтому: отключаем мозги и действуем!***

Ср. с примерами из Нацкорпуса:

*Стихотворение написано античным размером, сапфической строфой, с короткой последней строкой. В трех одиннадцатисложниках, как в греческом театре, происходит какое-то действие, но в последней выходит хор и, как ему и положено, говорит о главном. [**Поэтому:**](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%EE%FD%F2%EE%EC%F3&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=bcolon&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=1&docid=54939&sid=352) приглядимся и прислушаемся к тому, о чем вещает хор греческой трагедии. Пробежимся вместе с цветущим немецким юношей по коротким четвертым строчкам…* [Андрей Балдин, Алексей Прокопьев. Конькобег. Гармонист // «Октябрь», 2002]

*Неприменимость знания к жизни есть тоже признак культуры, причем уже достаточно высокой. [**Поэтому:**](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%EE%FD%F2%EE%EC%F3&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=bcolon&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=2&docid=48710&sid=882) кто великий, кто большой, кто замечательный, кто знаменитый, кто прославленный, кто выдающийся, кто гениальный ― есть не только расхожая пошлость человеческих амбиций, в частности литературных, но и устав, в самом армейском смысле, культуры.* [Андрей Битов. Жизнь без нас (1997)]